# asp.net is using the code of a controller even though that controller was deleted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am doing some development on an asp.net web application. Using ISS with a mssql db backend. I was trying to modify one of the controllers for an error page, but I noticed it had no effect. Just as a test, I deleted the controller entirely yet the application is still functioning as though its there. The view displays a table entry ID based on the error, which is passed to it through the ViewBag in the controller.

I have several versions of this application, so I made sure that I was running and testing the current one. As a precaution I even deleted all copies of the controller, and restarted the web application in ISS. Still, when I purposefully navigate to an Unexpected-Error page, it is acting as though it is running off of the controller which I deleted.

```
@using RS.Core.Lib;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Unexpected Error";
    var ctrlr = ViewContext.Controller as RS.Web.Controllers._Controller;
    var appLogId = (int)ViewBag.AppLogId;
}

<center>
    <h3>Oops! An unexpected error has occured.</h3>
    <p>
        Please browse <a href="javascript: history.go(-1);">back</a> and try again.
    </p>
    <p>
        @if( ctrlr.GetSession().HasPermission("APP_LOG_CAN_USE") )
        {
            <span>(Error Log Id: <a href='/sysadmin/app_log'>@(appLogId))</a></span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span>(Error Log Id: @(appLogId))</span>
        }
    </p>
</center>
```

One would expect that no applogid would be passed to the view, however this is the case and it is generating new ID's as well, which should not be the case because the controller dealt with that too.

Comment: So you re-built and re-deployed the asp.net project dll?

Comment: No I just restarted the Web-App in ISS

Comment: Are you testing this locally or on a remote server?

Answer (score 2):

Asp.Net controllers are compiled C# code that must be built before deploying. Any time you make a change to a controller, you must re-build the project and redeploy it in order to see the changes. This might be confusing if you are familiar with client-side javascript, which is not pre-compiled, but interpreted by the browser.